# regex matches wrong strings

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to use `regex.h` with no success. I'm trying to match an IP address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define No_Regex_Flags 0

void check_RE(char * r, regex_t RE)
{
    printf ("%s - %s\n", r, !regexec(&RE, r, 0, NULL, 0) ? "Match" : "No Match");
}

int main ()
{
    regex_t regex;
    int ret = regcomp(&regex, "[0-9]{1,3}.{3}[0-9]{1,3}", No_Regex_Flags);
    if(ret)
        printf("err1\n");

    char  RE_list[][32] = 
    {
        "0.0.0.0",
        "123.456.789.123",
        "a.b.c.d",
        "1.2.34.567",
        "1111.1.1.1",
        ".1.1.1",
        "1,1,1,1"
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(RE_list) / sizeof(RE_list[0]); i++)
        check_RE(RE_list[i], regex);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output I get is always a match:

```
0.0.0.0 - Match
123.456.789.123 - Match
a.b.c.d - Match
1.2.34.567 - Match
1111.1.1.1 - Match
.1.1.1 - Match
1,1,1,1 - Match
```

Why is that?

Comment: Didn't change... Also, wouldn't the anchors accept empty strings? quoting MAN: `Match-beginning-of-line operator (^) matches the empty string immediately after a newline`

Comment: The dot must be escaped and the first number with dot pattern must be grouped, the limiting quantifier should quantify that group. Also, anchor the pattern and use `REG_EXTENDED` flag: `"^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$"` + `regcomp(&regex, "^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", REG_EXTENDED)`

Comment: Looks like my answer is complete now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
int ret = regcomp(&regex, "^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Or, a more efficient one:

```
int ret = regcomp(&regex, "^[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6zuTt/1) that also matches wrong IP addresses like `1.2.34.567` and `123.456.789.123`. So, I'd suggest a more precise one (source: [regular-expresions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)):

```
"^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}$"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6zuTt/2/).

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/bRzUQL). The output is

```
0.0.0.0 - Match
123.456.789.123 - No Match
a.b.c.d - No Match
1.2.34.567 - No Match
1111.1.1.1 - No Match
.1.1.1 - No Match
1,1,1,1 - No Match
```

**POIs**

- The dot matches any char, so you must escape it with `\\` in the pattern
- If you have to repeat a sequence of patterns, you need to *group* them and quantify the group: `[0-9]{1,3}\\.{3}` => `([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}`
- To match the whole string, you need *anchors*, `^` and `$` around the pattern
- To make the `$` anchor work, you need to pass `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp`. It is also required if you plan to use `{3}` without having to escape the `{` and `}`. Else, you would have to follow the BRE POSIX specs and write a limiting quantifier like `\{3\}`
- As `[0-9]{1,3}` matches any 3 digits, the original pattern is not really validating IP addresses, so you need to restrict the octet values to `0`..`255`. Thus, an alternation group `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])` should be used to match one octet.

Here is the octet pattern explanation:

- `25[0-5]` - `250` to `255`
- `|` - or
- `2[0-4][0-9]` - `200` to `249`
- `|` - or
- `1[0-9][0-9]` - `100` to `199`
- `|` - or
- `[1-9]?[0-9]` - `0` to `99`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! what about <username>:<password> regex? I though of `"^[a-zA-Z0-9$-_.+!*'(),]+:[a-zA-Z0-9$-_.+!*'(),]+$"`

Comment: @CIsForCookies You are welcome. Password regex depends on the requirements, and it is a different question. Just note that `$-_` creates a range inside the bracket expression.

Comment: Ok, I have one final question about a file path. Would this regex have any obvious problems I missed? `"^[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[/]?]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$"`

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yes, a lot. It does not match any Windows file path (like `C:\Windows\test.txt`), and it does not match lots of valid Linux file paths. You know, there are files without extensions. And `[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[/]?]*` looks fishy. Probably you meant `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*`. You are re-inventing a wheel here. Use the dedicated libraries if you can find any.